# dividing bigdecimal containing bigger dividers than scale

Tags: java, android, scale, bigdecimal

I want to find a way to scale divisions of bigdecimals that can contain diverse numbers.

if I use this code:

> r= x.divide(y,10, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

the result of almost all results are correct, but if I have a divisor with more digits before point than the scale, the result is 0.0000000000.

What I have to do to obtain the correct precision on these divisions?

> 1 / 3 =0.3333333333 (scale 10)
>
> 1 / 151545545664651878 = 1.515455456646E-17 (for example)
>
> 100000000000000 / 3 = 3.3333333333E+14

thanks.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Can you show us how what you get is different from what you want?  How do you actually **view** the numbers?

Comment: Sorry, I don't speak english well. The input is an edit text and output is the same editText.setText (result). On editText you can put the number to divide, so actually it have got be able to divide almost all numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way. It's realizing operations with mathcontext instead of scale.
It seems that  MathContext constructor uses precission not scale.

with MathContext

```
MathContext mc = new MathContext(10, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
BigDecimal r = x.divide(y, mc);
Log.i("mc","r = " + r);
```

with Scale

```
BigDecimal r = x.divide(y,10, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);   
Log.i("scale","r = " + r);
```

If I realize this division : 
1 / 3333333333333333333333333 =

The first output :  3.0000000000E-19
And the second output: 0E-10

So, set Scale to a big decimal seems the same of Scale in MathContext but it isn't. 
I hope it could helps someone.